# Support for both reference types and value types

Tags: c#, generics

I`ve got this class with this method where I require to support for both reference types and value types but I do not know how exactly how to perform this. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
public static class CacheHelper<T>
{
    public static T Get(string key, Func<T> function) {
        var obj = (T)HttpContext.Current.Cache[key];
        if (obj == null)
        {
            obj = function.Invoke();
            HttpContext.Current.Cache.Add(key, obj, null, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(3),
                TimeSpan.Zero, System.Web.Caching.CacheItemPriority.Normal, null);
        }
        return (T)obj;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well I'd start by not casting to `T` before checking for nullity... it's possible that just removing that cast in the first line of the body will fix it.

Comment: @JonSkeet: But then, the `if` block will be skipped if `obj` is *anything* other than `null`, even if it is not of type `T`. While your suggestion may fix the compilability, I doubt that is what the OP had in mind.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Well it will fail in the `return` statement, which will throw a `InvalidCastException`... which would otherwise happen on the first statement. The result is the same either way... and to be honest, if you're using the same key for two different types, you're probably doing it wrong to start with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think if you remove the cast to `T` on this line `var obj = HttpContext.Current.Cache[key];` you should be fine.

```
public static class CacheHelper<T>
{
    public static T Get(string key, Func<T> function) {
        var obj = HttpContext.Current.Cache[key];
        if (obj == null)
        {
            obj = function.Invoke();
            HttpContext.Current.Cache.Add(key, obj, null, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(3),
                TimeSpan.Zero, System.Web.Caching.CacheItemPriority.Normal, null);
        }
        return (T)obj;
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't look like the original code. Apparently, the OP wants to retrieve an object from `function` if whatever is found in that cache is not of type `T`.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I think the purpose is to Get or add a value to the cache. Very much like when working with ConcurrentDictionary see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee378677(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: It rather looks like the purpose is to get, add or *replace* a value in the cache, to guarantee the postcondition that the respective item is in the cache after the operation, *and that it is of type `T`*. I'd kindly like to ask the OP to clarify whether that is indeed the intended purpose in the question.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: I don't see anything in the original code which checks whether the type is right. If the OP had used `as` instead of a cast, you'd have a point... but if the currently cached version is of the wrong type, it will just throw an exception, *not* create a new value.

Comment: @JonSkeet: My suspicion is that the OP wanted "something like" `as`, but couldn't use `as` because they didn't want to add the `class` constraint on `T`. Therefore, for the time being, the "nearest thing", namely an exception-throwing cast was used. Yes, currently, an exception will be thrown an `obj` will not become `null`, but my understanding is that that is exactly what the question is about.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Well I can't see *any* indication of that within the original question - whereas this answer achieves what I think the OP *was* asking for, in that it will still detect the absence of a value. I guess we'll have to see whether the OP responds to requests for clarification...